# Time Profiler vs. CPU Sampler?

Tags: ios, instruments

In Instruments, what's the difference between the Time Profiler and the CPU Sampler?

I'm interested in understanding how each collects data, and what type of problem each is designed to solve.

Comment: Some good background reading on [profilers is available on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Statistical_profilers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Instruments User Guide lists the following differences between the Time Profiler and Sampler instruments:

- The Time Profiler instrument is more efficient at gathering data.
- The Time Profiler instrument can gather data from all running processes. The Sampler instrument can gather data from only one process.
- The Time Profiler instrument can sample running threads. The Sampler instrument can only sample all thread states.

The Time Profiler and Sampler instruments are similar. In most cases you should use the Time Profiler instrument since it does everything the Sampler instrument does and does it more efficiently.

Comment: ... and where Sampler should be used?

Comment: If you're running an older version of Instruments that doesn't have the Time Profiler instrument, you should use Sampler. The OpenGL ES Driver template includes the Sampler instrument. It's easier to stick with the Sampler instrument than add the Time Profiler instrument to the trace.